# Unable to pull docker images; write operation not permitted

Tags: docker

I'm unable to pull docker images. Error message is as follows:

> $docker pull docker
> Using default tag: latest
> Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.121.0.1:53: write udp 192.168.1.9:39305->10.121.0.1:53: write: operation not permitted

Running "dig registry-1.docker.io" yields following:

```
$ dig registry-1.docker.io

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> registry-1.docker.io
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 63847
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 8, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;registry-1.docker.io.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
registry-1.docker.io.   3600    IN  A   3.209.182.229
registry-1.docker.io.   3600    IN  A   18.214.230.110
registry-1.docker.io.   3600    IN  A   34.198.213.42
registry-1.docker.io.   3600    IN  A   34.192.204.44
registry-1.docker.io.   3600    IN  A   54.85.56.253
registry-1.docker.io.   3600    IN  A   52.20.81.6
registry-1.docker.io.   3600    IN  A   52.72.232.213
registry-1.docker.io.   3600    IN  A   107.23.149.57

;; Query time: 228 msec
;; SERVER: 10.86.0.1#53(10.86.0.1)
;; WHEN: 五 11月 05 16:37:25 CST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 177
```

Comment: Are you able to do `dig registry-1.docker.io`?

Comment: Pls see update.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  When I ran:

```
$ sudo docker compose up -d
```

I got:

```
[+] Running 1/0
✘ webserver Error                                                                                                       
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.8.1:53: write udp 192.168.8.215:55182->192.168.8.1:53: write: operation not permitted
```

The problem was caused because I had connected to a VPN which adjusted DNS settings after the docker service had started (I'm using Debain).  After restarting the docker service:

```
$ sudo service docker restart
```

my docker compose command worked:

```
$ sudo docker compose up -d
[+] Running 14/14
 ✔ webserver 13 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                          171.7s 
   ✔ 68ced04f60ab Pull complete                                                                                        102.7s 
   ✔ 1d2a5d8fa585 Pull complete                                                                                        102.8s 
   ✔ 5d59ec4ae241 Pull complete                                                                                        165.6s 
   ✔ d42331ef4d44 Pull complete                                                                                        165.7s 
   ✔ 408b7b7ee112 Pull complete                                                                                        166.4s 
   ✔ 570cd47896d5 Pull complete                                                                                        166.4s 
   ✔ 2419413b2a16 Pull complete                                                                                        166.5s 
   ✔ 2c7832852643 Pull complete                                                                                        166.7s 
   ✔ 8b0b209a25bc Pull complete                                                                                        166.8s 
   ✔ 46011418685f Pull complete                                                                                        167.5s 
   ✔ 68be3748ea55 Pull complete                                                                                        167.6s 
   ✔ 4e3af655ec1e Pull complete                                                                                        167.7s 
   ✔ 9f579d3b7159 Pull complete                                                                                        167.8s 
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Network portal_default        Created                                                                                 0.1s 
 ✔ Container portal-webserver-1  Started
```